# Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to double

Tags: java, double

The error on this line is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to double`

The thing is all the values im calculating are doubles, I'm really confused.

```
 if(price == minprice < .20 * minprice){
```

Its been a few years since I last programmed in Java so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Please express that condition in words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing a boolean value to a double.
Here is a breakdown of what that line is doing:

`price == minprice` will give a **boolean** indicating if price is equal to minprice, which you are then asking if it is less than `.20*minprice`.
So you are asking if the **boolean answer** you get from `price == minprice` is less than `.20*minprice`.

Basicly, your code is equivalent to:

```
if((price==minprice) < .20*minprice){...
```

Java evaluates each expression in order. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to calculate, but a correct statement would be:

```
if(price < .20*minprice){...
```